# GET Events not returning all attendees

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

Using the .NET SDK to query Graph api for events.  In cases where there are multiple attendees, the result data only includes the organizer and a maximum of 2 additional attendees in the Attendees collection.

```
var request = this.graphClient.Users[spaceId].Calendar.Events.Request();
```

Interestingly, when using the Graph Explorer I see the same behavior, though I cannot confirm that those meetings have more than 3 attendees. (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer?request=me/calendar/events&method=GET&version=v1.0#)

Is this a default limit in the API itself, or perhaps an Exchange configuration that needs to be changed?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this behavior. I'm able to pull events with well over 10 attendees without a problem. I suspect something else is going on here. Could you include a bit more of the code you're using? The token you're using might also help sort out what is going on (less likely but certainly worth looking at anyway).

Comment: Can you provide a http capture of the request and response with PII removed? That'd really help.